# How to change device input language programmatically

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing an ionic application in which user should fill three fields, each one in different language. I don't want the user to change their writing language manually but rather i want the input language to be changed automatically when focusing on some field.

Comment: This question is too broad. Try to provide relevant code, what you have tried and encountered issue.

Comment: @Alexei i didn't tried any thing because i searched but doesn't find anything. i think the answer would be a one line of code, or i have to use a third party plug-in